# What happens if debtor changes address?

Tags: nevada

I have an Arizona judgement  against someone who ran away to Nevada. How do I domesticate it in Nevada  or do I even need to? What evidence, documents etc does the court want to show they moved? I learned  it from a PI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an Arizona judgement against someone who ran away to Nevada.
>   How do I domesticate it in Nevada or do I even need to?

You need to domesticate it in Nevada using the procedure set forth below.

> What evidence, documents etc does the court want to show they moved? I
>   learned it from a PI.

You need the documents described below. The court does not need any evidence to show that they moved. It just needs evidence that you have a valid judgement from another U.S. state as described below, and that needs to be served (i.e. notice has to be given in a specified way) to the debtor.

> Nevada . . .  has enacted the Uniform Enforcement of Foreign Judgments
>   Act, [which] permits enforcement of a judgment from another state upon
>   the mere act of filing it in the office of a Clerk of the District
>   Court and paying the required filing fee. The act of filing the
>   foreign judgment gives it the effect of being a judgment of the court
>   in the state in which it is filed. The process of enforcement then
>   goes forward as if the judgment is a domestic one.
>
> The Uniform Foreign Judgment Act, what was first adopted in Nevada in
>   1979 as set forth below, allows the state to enforce a judgment from
>   another state without the expense of litigation. There are notable
>   exceptions, which is why legal action should be commenced in the state
>   where the defendant is domiciled. A foreign judgment must be filed
>   with the Clerk of the District Court in the county in which the
>   attempt is being made to enforce the judgment. This should include any
>   enforcement proceedings such as the Writ of Execution upon assets,
>   etc. The steps that must be taken are as follows:
>
> Obtain an original exemplified copy of the judgment (a triple
>   certified copy) from the court where the judgment was granted (see
>   further explanation of the three signatures required below). NRS
>   17.350
>
> File an application with the exemplified judgment together with a
>   filing fee, with the District Court Clerk, and an affidavit which
>   includes the name and last known address of all parties to the
>   judgment, together with a description as to how much remains due on
>   the judgment, and the extent to which it has been satisfied. See NRS
>   17. 360 below.
>
> File a “NOTICE OF FILING APPLICATION FOR FOREIGN JUDGMENT AND AFFIAVIT
>   OF ATTORNEY FOR THE JUDGMENT CREDITOR” and attach thereto file stamped
>   copies of the Application (including the exemplified copy of the
>   judgment) and Affidavit of the attorney for the judgment creditor, and
>   then mail this Notice by Certified Mail to all judgment parties. NRS
>   17.360(2).
>
> File an Affidavit of Service evidencing the mailing of the above
>   documents to all judgment parties.
>
> The plaintiff may also choose to record a certified copy of the Notice
>   of Filing Application for Foreign Judgment and Affidavit of the
>   Attorney for Judgment Creditor in any county in Nevada where the
>   defendant may own real property either now or in the future.
>
> [A court can] deny recognizing the foreign judgment [for certain
>   reasons]. One reason for denial is an appeal, which is pending in the
>   original court that first issued the judgment.. A “stay” may be
>   granted if a debtor can allege grounds exist in the court’s
>   jurisdiction where the foreign judgment is being filed, thus creating
>   a “stay” preventing the foreign judgment from being recorded. Such
>   grounds include: lack of sufficient notice in obtaining the original
>   judgment, the judgment was obtained by fraud, the cause of action
>   conflicts with state policies in the state where the foreign judgment
>   is to be filed, the judgment conflicts with another final judgment,
>   the original case is on appeal or being challenged by motion, or lack
>   of jurisdiction over the debtor in the original judgment, etc.
>
> A “stay” by the debtor must be filed within 30 days of receipt of the
>   notice of the filing of the foreign judgment. Thirty (30) days after a
>   foreign judgment is filed and notice has been given to the judgment
>   debtor, the creditor may begin enforcement of the judgment by means
>   allowed by law within the state in which the foreign judgment has been
>   domesticated in the State of Nevada.

From [here](https://albrightstoddard.com/enforcement-foreign-judgements-nevada/).

Comment: Does the address on the judgment  change to their new address?

Comment: @user30567 Judgments don't have addresses. Judgments are against people, not places (unless it is a declaration as to who owns or has possession of real property).